# how to disable WebService call from other domains

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

i want to avoid the others to access my webservice.

I have Web Service called WebService.asmx, which is hosted in www.xyz.com
   and we know that we can access the service like
   http://www.xyz.com/WebService.asmx

1. How to avoid Listing all the Functions
2. Other should not Add as " Web Reference and they should call my web service functions "

please help me to solved these issues, my project is running and i want to avoid this issues...

advance thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to restrict access to an ASMX Webservice, i.e. the asmx page and its WSDL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400198/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-access-to-an-asmx-webservice-i-e-the-asmx-page-and)

Comment: Thanks, Peter J your simple trick is helped lot... I used Cookies concept.... this is really awesome.... 
Set Cookies Before Call & Remove after that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to authenticate all your requests to your methods and reject the calls that are not authenticated. A very detailed answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400198/is-there-a-way-to-restrict-access-to-an-asmx-webservice-i-e-the-asmx-page-and).

Comment: you mean, to all functions ?

Comment: its more than 1000 functions... do have any link as an example... please share it..

Comment: i have added the link.

Comment: it will show functions, but if you have implemented authentication than no one will be authenticated to use them unless you give them credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Web Services can be checked form the firewall where request is coming. It can checked by the content-type of the response. All webservices have "application/soap-xml" as content-type.